# Online peer to peer connection

Tags: iphone, xcode

Here i am developing an application which uses peer to peer connection. i am able to communicate using WIFI and Bluetooth connection. i.e a devices with in a same local network are able to communicate with each other.

Is it possible to communicate online using Bonjour service or any other option for online communication.

Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour works only in the local network, because the devices communicate via multicast
DNS (IP: 224.0.0.251). You could use Wide Area Bonjour with the cooperation of a DNS server.
Under http://www.dns-sd.org/ServerSetup.html you find a description how to set that up on Unix.

Other than that I don't think there is any special support by Apple. You have to set up some kind of server on the Internet yourself.

Comment: Hey ,

I am interested in it, Can u shed more light on it ?

How to set up the network ?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you interested in? Can you ask a specific question?